# Why doesn't the date picker change the Buddha calendar year?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, datepicker

I want to change the year in my calendar to Buddhist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ3RJ.png)

I've tried overwriting the `formatYear` function in `GlobalMaterialLocalizations`. But it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

expecting : `2023(year) + 543 = 2566`

my code :

main

```
MaterialApp(
      ...
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('th', '')],
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        CustomLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: const Locale('th', ''),
    );
```

CustomLocalizations

```
abstract class CustomLocalizations implements MaterialLocalizations {
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> delegate =
      _CustomLocalizationsDelegate();
}


class _CustomLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  const _CustomLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == 'th';

  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    final localeName = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(locale.toString());

    final data = date_localizations.dateSymbols[localeName];
    initializeDateFormattingCustom(
      locale: localeName,
      symbols: data,
      patterns: date_localizations.datePatterns[localeName],
    );

    return SynchronousFuture<MaterialLocalizations>(
        MaterialLocalizationCustom(localeName));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(covariant LocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

MaterialLocalizationCustom

```
class MaterialLocalizationCustom extends MaterialLocalizationTh {
  MaterialLocalizationCustom(String localeName)
      : super(
          fullYearFormat: DateFormat('y', localeName),
          compactDateFormat: DateFormat('yMd', localeName),
          shortDateFormat: DateFormat('yMMMd', localeName),
          mediumDateFormat: DateFormat('MMMEd', localeName),
          longDateFormat: DateFormat('yMMMMEEEEd', localeName),
          yearMonthFormat: DateFormat('MMMM y', localeName),
          shortMonthDayFormat: DateFormat('MMMd', localeName),
          decimalFormat: NumberFormat.decimalPattern(localeName),
          twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat: NumberFormat('00', localeName),
        );
        @override
        String formatYear(DateTime date) {
           final buddhistYear = date.year + 543;
           return buddhistYear.toString();
        }
}
```

Comment: can you add code snippet?